# Clarification of the slang meaning of "Choke"?

Tags: meaning, slang

[Choke](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=choke&defid=5161625)

> Has little or nothing to do with anticipated results. It's not limited to sports or competition. You can choke on an assignment for work, choke in an attempt to seduce a crush of yours. Jordan missing a free throw. You can choke anywhere, anytime.
>   Choking is when you had control, and failed to execute.
>
> What happens is you are suppose to be focused on what your eyes are viewing. But your weak mind chooses to worry about something negative whether real or not, past or future.
>
> It's bigger than that
>   Michael Jordan would be considered one of the most clutch professional sports players of all time.
>   Only you know when you choke. Its a distinct feeling. Choking doesn't give a crap about expectations.

The above quoted definition said it simply means performing below what you and others expect of. But does it also mean in a more core level, one performs not so well because of the nervousness one gets when the expectation is too high? Because this reminds me of a few lines from the song *Lose Yourself* where the rapper couldn't rap a word because of nervousness.

> His palms are sweaty, knees weak, arms are heavy
>   There's vomit on his sweater already, mom's spaghetti
>   He's nervous, but on the surface he looks calm and ready to drop bombs,
>   But he keeps on forgetting what he wrote down,
>   The whole crowd goes so loud
>   He opens his mouth, but the words won't come out
>   He's **choking** how, everybody's joking now
>   The clock's run out, time's up, over, bloah!
>   Snap back to reality, Oh there goes gravity
>   Oh, there goes Rabbit, he **choked**
>   He's so mad, but he won't give up that

Comment: Your paraphrase of the definition, *it simply means performing below what you and others expect*, contradicts the first sentence of the definition, *has little or nothing to do with anticipated results*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's just asking us to comment on a highly subjective "definition" in UrbanDictionary.

Comment: NOAD has a more straightforward definition: **choke** (*v.*) `informal` (in sports) _fail to perform at a crucial point of a game or contest owing to a failure of nerve_. I think that matches the context of the rap song, given that it talks about a crowd and the clock.

Comment: @J.R. thanks for finding such reliable source of word definition.But can you elaborate a bit of the phrase "failure of nerve"? Does it mean a feeling of nervousness or a courage problem or a you-didn't-believe-in-yourself-enough problem ?

Comment: @user49119 - Yes. (In other words, it can mean any of those, or some combination of those.) Imagine yourself taking a free throw in basketball, or a putt on the golf green. Usually, you're relaxed and reliable. But, with 3.2 seconds left in a playoff game, or on the last hole of a close competition, you find yourself unable to relax.  Your knees seem stiff. You grip the club tighter than usual. You're about to have a "failure of nerve" (in other words, you're about to _choke_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main sense of *choke* is "cannot breathe".

The word *choke* can be used literally (like when someone chokes you by squeezing your neck), or figuratively (like when you are about to deliver your presentation, you have the mic ready, and are going to speak the first word, but no words come out--you choke!)

Consequently, we are likely to fail to execute when we choke. (Jordan missing a free throw, for example.)

The definition of *choke* you gave is about the feeling in that precise moment. Sometimes nobody else knows that you choked. Both literal and figurative meanings fit the lyrics well. (It's very explicit about the words won't come out).

> *He opens his mouth, but the words won't come out*
>   *He's choking how, everybody's joking now* -- (He can't sing; he's just standing there, frozen.)
>   *[...]*
>   *Oh there goes gravity*
>   *Oh, there goes Rabbit, he choked* -- (I believe Rabbit refers to Eminem himself. Again, he choked.)